# In React Table , dropdown list in td for last rows are getting hidden

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-table

using react-table and react-select created Dropdown list and assigned to td in table , in last rows the dropdown values are not displaying i mean hidden below the table.

Comment: increase the z-index maybe ?

Comment: Can you share code OR image showing this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to inspect and find the corresponding tag of the outer most table. Now try to change element style -> overflow: visible

Now you can add corresponding css into your react app also